# Parse XML string in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

I am trying to parse a particular attribute/value pair from XML in VB.NET.

The XML is originally a string that looks like XML but it needs to be converted to an XML-like datatype or structure before I can parse it.

How can I convert this string into XML, and then parse the info that I need?

EDIT:

`Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(str)` gets the string into xml, however `Call doc.attribute("name").Value` doesn't work. I've confirmed that the name of the Sub that I'm trying to call is correct. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried converting the value of the XML back into a string. Is here a special datatype for Subs? Am I missing something else?

**Edit2**
The value of the XML attribute is the name of a function. I'd like to call different functions based on the value of the value, which will be changed by me via a flash activex control. I pretty much have total control over what values i'm dealing with here.

(Do I need a delegate function? )

Edit3:

I got it. 
'CallByName()' with appropriate arguments.

Comment: There's no `XML datatype` in .NET. Can you be a little more specific? Give an example of how the XML looks like and what attribute/value you'd like to obtain from it. Also why is this tagged with `flash`,  `axshockwaveflash` and `call`?

Comment: @Darin - the XML is coming from an axshockwaveflash control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(str)
```

Comment: This gets me the XML string into an XML object. I still can't call the function... It's a start though.

Answer (score 2):

What function are you talking about calling? "Value"? That's not a function. It's a property.

```
Dim val As Object = doc.Attribute("name").Value
```

Comment: And how can I call the function whose name is stored in val?

Comment: @Moshe: you never said you have the name of a function stored in the XML. I have no idea how to call a function whose name is stored in a string, I only know it's usually a bad idea to play such games.

Comment: @Moshe: if there are a limited number of possible functions, then just use a switch statement. I strongly suggest you not try to get fancy with doing dynamic function calls through reflection or something. That can be very difficult to maintain.

Comment: @John - I would have to disagree on both counts. Dynamic function calls are easier than a switch statement to maintain because I won't forget to add cases. Also, there are an unknown number of functions at this point. Thanks.

Comment: @Moshe: dynamic function calls are tougher to maintain because they need to be maintained by someone who uderstands dynamic function calls. A far larger number of developers know what a switch statement is.

Comment: @John - ah. I didn't understand you before in regards to mauntaining it. This happens to be a (proprietary) program fo r myself. The idea is that I won't need to rely on swf studio or flash jester to make Flash access system functions like a regular desktop app. I don't know what functions exactly I need except that they are likely to change, hence dynamic function calls.

Comment: @Moshe: good luck. In most shops, not everyone knows Reflection. In yours, everyone already does.

Comment: @ John -  Reflection? Is that the term for dynamic functions? Cool, you live and learn. Thanks for your time.